# Why is the word "Done" issued to console by apt-get update not there if executed remotely?

Tags: apt, 20.04

Imagine you have a check of a remote system that correctly executes an `apt-get update`.

Typically, I have seen as resulting printout there this line:

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

By occasion, with Ubuntu 20.04, I've found out though the following:

- if you execute `apt-get update` *locally*, the system says, `Reading package lists... Done`;
- if you execute `apt-get update` *remotely*, the system says only, `Reading package lists...` that is the word "Done" is missing.

Previously, I haven't observed this behavior with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

What could be the reason?

Below: console excerpt with the described Bash exercise and corresponding output.

```
localuser@ho:/tmp$ ssh -i /tmp/.ssh-dbg20-puzzled-mendel-1690/one  remoteuser@122.110.163.114 lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
localuser@ho:/tmp$ ssh -i /tmp/.ssh-dbg20-puzzled-mendel-1690/one  remoteuser@122.110.163.114 "sudo apt-get update"
Hit:1 http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists...
localuser@ho:/tmp$ 
localuser@ho:/tmp$ ssh -i /tmp/.ssh-dbg20-puzzled-mendel-1690/one  remoteuser@122.110.163.114
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Last login: Tue Jul  7 23:38:45 2020 from 112.110.123.123
remoteuser@dbg20-puzzled-mendel-1690:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.stw-bonn.de/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
remoteuser@dbg20-puzzled-mendel-1690:~$
```

Comment: Try `ssh -t ...  remoteuser@122.110.163.114 sudo apt-get update`, allocating a TTY

Comment: @muru haha thank you this works!

Comment: `expect` is a tool that lets you automate conversations with asynchronous entities. That's what I imagine for checking remote systems. Or, invoke a tool/script on the server that makes all the checks you want, and returns a "Healthy: Y/N".